# IOS Destination Path

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using the code of Erica Sadun to Synchronous Downloads files.

On the example of this code the Destination Path is :

[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/"]

the issue I am facing is when you kill app the files disappear and is needed to download again.

What is the path to save files inside app without to download any more the files ?

Comment: The app should not auto delete files from the Documents folder if they are getting saved there.  Are you sure thats where they are going?  If you are working in the sim, you can browse to the folder in Finder to see if the files are indeed showing up there.  If they disappear when you kill the app, either they are not 100% downloaded, or there is some code in your app that is deleting them.

Comment: I am able to read the file when finish downloading doing that :


- (IBAction)plays {

 MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.savePath]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:theMovie];
 [theMovie play];
 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to read the file in documents folder when finish downloading whith that :

```
- (IBAction)plays { MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]   initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.savePath]]; [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:theMovie]; [theMovie play]; }
```